# How to automatically load QGIS actions

Tags: qgis, actions

There is something that I like alot in QGIS, and that is actions. From automatic wikipedia search, to opening an image, this use makes QGIS feel very dynamic.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to automatically load up a default list of actions when opening a specific shapefile. So I have to create new actions every time I reload the exact same shapefile. Very annoying.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are stored in the style of the layer. So, you have to set the action and save the style. When you import a new shape you have just to load the style and you will have your action.
Because I think you are using this action for different geometry types, it could be usefull for you to create different default styles for point, line and polygon.